# The test coverage percentage is decreased when update Angular to 13

Tags: angular, migration, test-coverage

I've migrated the project from the older version into v13, and I found that the test coverage percentage has decreased.

So, I have looked at the test coverage results for both v12 and v13. Seems like the test did not cover the method if the method never got called with `callThrough` which is correct IMO.

[Test Coverage Angular V12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdsBN.png)
[Test Coverage Angular V13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mKL6.png)

Even that, I still need to know the root cause of this problem.
Do anyone has clue or suggestion on this approach?

**Note:**

I've also tried to change the `target` in `tsconfig.json` to use `es2015` and seems like I got the same result with test result in Angular v13

tsconfig.json (v12, change `target` to `es2015`)

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

[Test Coverage Angular V12, change `target` to `es2015`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qENMO.png)

So I think it might be related to the reason of the coverage change.

---

**Project's Code:**

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "test-angular-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rm -rf coverage/ && ng test --code-coverage --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

app.component.spec.ts

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'testAngularApp'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('testAngularApp');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span')?.textContent).toContain('testAngularApp app is running!');
  });
});
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'testAngularApp';

  testFunc() {
    console.log(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should show the code coverage summaries which the actual percentages. If the percentage difference is not significant, then why worry about it? You should expect things to change after a migration.